# HTML 5 Video not working on IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, flash, html5-video, video-encoding

Why video on [this page](http://videojs.com/) and [this page](http://www.bodhibikes.com/welcome-to-bodhi-bikes.php) working in all browser but not in Microsoft Internet explorer 9?

Any fix for it?

This video is not playing on My IE 9.0.8112.16421

My OS is Windows 7 64 bit

[image]

Comment: This video plays just fine in IE9 RTM.

Comment: Thanks I added my IE info in question.

Comment: Video played fine for me as well on IE 9.0.8112.16421, as did the video from the videojs.com site.

Comment: @kinakuta - then what could be the problem on my PV :(

Comment: Good question. Can you play the mp4 video directly from the OS? I would also try uninstalling and re-installing IE9 on the off chance you have a corrupted or missing dll (although I'd expect you'd get an error with either condition.)

Comment: What exactly happens? Do you see error messages in the F12 Developer Tools? If you right-click the video and choose "Save", can you save the file to your desktop and play it?

Comment: Is Windows running on a Virtual Machine or a Physical Machine?

Comment: Do you have Media Player installed? (you probably do, but HTML5 video won't work on IE9 without it).

Answer (score 3):

Some versions of IE9 require an absolute path to the video file for some reason.

For example:

```
<video poster="big_buck_bunny/poster.jpg" controls>
  <source src="http://www.example.com/big_buck_bunny/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
  <source src="http://www.example.com/big_buck_bunny/trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

The MIME type returned by the server is also quite important as Jason Dorell said.

I was using `<video>` tag on a website and while writing it in localhost everything worked perfectly. Once uploaded into the server, the `<video>` stopped working only in IE (Firefox and Chrome still worked fine).

After digging a bit into it, I simply added `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` into the `.htaccess` file and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

the problem maybe the type of file try with this:

```
<video poster="big_buck_bunny/poster.jpg" controls>
  <source src="big_buck_bunny/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
  <source src="big_buck_bunny/trailer.ogg" type="video/ogg" >
  <source src="big_buck_bunny/trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

big_buck_bunny/trailer.* is your video

Answer (score 1):

It could also be an error in the compatibility detection : Just a theory =X

**Taken from: videojs: main.js (line 249-255)**

```
// Check if the browser supports video.
browserSupportsVideo: function() {
    if (typeof VideoJS.videoSupport != "undefined") { return VideoJS.videoSupport; }
    VideoJS.videoSupport = !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
    return VideoJS.videoSupport;
}
```

Cause the fallback to flash is i believe, quite reliable, after this detection. I do not have IE 9.0.8... : So you could give this code a run, to see if this is true/false

```
var test = function() {
    return (!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType);
}
```

If this is true, i may consider forking the file : And adding a fail for IE 9.0.8...

It would not surprise me if IE did a half-hearted video support halfway : And this means of detection broke, in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue. The two example pages you linked to let me click the play button which then changes to a pause button but the videos do not *play*.

The java script i tried to help track down the issue returns null.
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].error);

I did stumble upon this though:
I'm using the **N** distribution of **Windows 7 64Bit**. [This msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff959805) suggests that the reason that my IE9 will not play video is that my distribution of windows did not come with media player or "Media Features" is turned off.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to get flv files playing in IE9 using SVG and the [google SVGWeb project](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/). Which is what started me looking at this whole HTML5 video thing. The [KB968212](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19289) download fixed my flv playback issue so i'm no longer looking for a fix for HTML5 video in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

If it's still not working here's what may certainly be a solution: encode the mp4 with compression format H.264. If you encode it with format mpeg4 or divx or else it will not work on IE9 and may as well crash Google Chrome. To do that, I use Any Video Converter freeware. But it could be done with any good video tool out there.

I've been trying all solutions listed here and tried other workaround for days but the problem lied in the way I created my mp4. IE9 does not decode other format than H.264.

Hope this helps,
Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the content type being returned from the server is "video/mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem could be in the installed video codecs, and different browsers may play video in different ways (from the point of inner implementation).

Try to install e.g. [K-Lite codec pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) and see what happens.

p.s. those videos work fine on my Win 7 x64 within IE9 x86 and IE9 x64

Answer (score -1):

In IE9 There is **no flash** video but a **HTML5** `<video>` element used, it tries to load:

```
http://www.bodhibikes.com/_/video/WELCOME_TO_BODHI_840_472.mp4
```

And that fails somehow. You should specify  [a correct videoformat](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) for both IE/Chrome?etc...